# Java - Can you cast an object into a class it doesn't extend?

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

Another way to ask the same question is, given 2 classes A and B, is it synonymous to say: "Object A can be cast into B" and "Object A is a descendant of B"?

Thanks,

JDelage

**Edit:** Clarified the question to make it clearer that both A and B are classes.

Comment: What do you mean by "direct descendant"? If you mean that class A explicitly extends B, then it isn't necessary. A could extend C and C could extend B, and it would still be possible to cast A to B.

Comment: @Sergey - Yes, that's what I mean by direct descendant.

Comment: Then replace "direct descendant" with "descendant" and your sentence will be correct. It doesn't matter how far up the inheritance tree you cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Java - Can you cast an object into a class it doesn't extend?*" - No, you can't.

"*Basically, is it synonymous to say: "Object A can be cast into B" and "Object A is a direct descendant of B"?*" - Yes. Plus in the case when A is of a class implementing interface B.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. It throws a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 2):

If it is not direct descendant or not the implementation of interface

```
class A;
class B extends A;
A a = new B(); 

interface A;
class B implements A;
(A) B
```

In other situation

It will throw ClassCastException http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, if B is interface and A is implementation of B

Comment: Fair enough - I meant B as a separate class, but my question didn't specify it.  Devil, details, and all that...  Thanks for the lesson.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have:

```
interface I {}
class A implements I {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}
```

all of the following are valid:

```
(I)C;
(A)C;
(B)C;
```