# Casting Stack to Iterable

Tags: java, casting, iterable

In the following code, the method returns a `Stack object` which gets casted to an `Iterable`.

```
public Iterable<Integer> getRoute(int x) {
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    ...
    stack.push(x);
    return stack;
}
```

Iterable is an interface and not a class. Could you please let me know, how does casting work here for this case?

Comment: This will not compile: List is an interface and you cannot instantiate interfaces.

Comment: [Have a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459517/java-can-you-cast-an-object-into-a-class-it-doesnt-extend)

Comment: you should at least follow javadoc first http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: @IngoBürk : Thanks. Though I know what casting does for subclasses, I wasn't sure how does it handle interfaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no actual casting here - just an implicit conversion from `Stack<Integer>` to `Iterable<Integer>` because [`Stack<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) implements `Iterable<E>` (implicitly, by extending `Vector<E>`, which extends `AbstractList<E>`, which extends `AbstractCollection<E>`, which implements `Collection<E>`, which extends `Iterable<E>`).

If it didn't implement the interface, the implicit conversion would be forbidden at compile-time, and an explicit cast would fail at execution time. Java doesn't use duck-typing.

Comment: Thanks! I knew how casting works for classes in general but wasn't sure what happens when implementing an interface.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, whenever an object is created, it is created as an object of a certain Class. A pointer to this object can then be stored in any variable of either the same Class, or a SuperClass of this class!

Casting is used when you want to go back from storing it as a superclass, to storing it as the same class that created it, or one of its lower superclasses.

A simple example, assuming that Sub is extending Super:

```
Super super = new Sub();
if (super instanceof Sub)
    Sub sub = (Sub) super;
```

Comment: Not related to my question. Iterable is not a class